# mat-select - mat-option sort values

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular6

I am new to Angular6 and I wanted to know if there is a simple way to do what I want.

I just read documentation and I did not read anything about that, is there a easy way to sort the value in the dropdown ?

```
<mat-form-field>
      <mat-select placeholder="Code List" required [(ngModel)]="contextScheme.codeListId">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let codeList of codeLists" [value]="codeList.codeListId">
            {{codeList.codeListName}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Basically the value I have are the values in my DB sorted by id, I want the exact thing but sorted in desc.

Thank in advance.

Sox-.

Answer (score 2):

You should do the sorting either on the database backend side, or as suggested by the Angular team in [no order-by pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe) it should be done inside the component.
E.g. if your have an array in the component, you could use [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: There is not any typescript method to reverse an array ? Thanks for your answer !

Comment: @Sox, yourArray.reverse() [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)